# Apparent paradox in non-null derivative but null primitive

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Suppose you have the function $\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{|y|^3}-\frac{1}{y^3}$, now this function is $0$ if $y>0$, and different from $0$ if $y<0$, but integrating this we get:
$$
\eta=\int^y\frac{1}{|y|^3}-\frac{1}{y^3}=\frac{1}{-2|y|^2}-\frac{1}{-2y^2} +C=\frac{1}{-2y^2}-\frac{1}{-2y^2}+C=0+C,\space \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
And this implies that  $\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y}=0,\space \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, which is not correct as seen above. Where is the loophole in my reasoning?

Comment: Don’t you pass over a discontinuity?

Comment: Also you’re integrating absolute values incorrectly.

Comment: I'm afraid you're correct both times. But I don't understand the second one, how do we integrate absolute values correctly?

Comment: Oh and you’re integrating the other term incorrectly too.

Comment: You gotta do it piecewise.

Comment: Correction, Taking into account the discontinuity and the absolute value, how should I proceed with the antiderivative? How could I find $\eta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirming part of your calculation:
$$\int y^{-3}\, dy = \frac{y^{-2}}{-2} + C = -\frac1{2y^2} + C.$$

With $f(y) = \lvert y\rvert^{-3},$ however, we have
$$
f(y) = \begin{cases}
 y^{-3} & y > 0, \\
-y^{-3} & y < 0,
\end{cases}
$$
with the function undefined at $0.$

We then have the antiderivative on $(0,\infty),$
$$\int \lvert y\rvert^{-3}\, dy = \int y^{-3}\, dy = -\frac1{2y^2} + C_1,$$
and the antiderivative on $(-\infty,0),$
$$\int \lvert y\rvert^{-3}\, dy = \int -y^{-3}\, dy = \frac1{2y^2} + C_2.$$

There is not a good way to integrate across zero.

Alternatively, let $g(y) = \dfrac1{\lvert y\rvert^3} - \dfrac1{y^3}.$ Then
$$
g(y) = \begin{cases}
 0 & y > 0, \\
-2y^{-3} & y < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
If we define $g(0) = 0$ then we have the antiderivative on $[0,\infty),$
$$\int g(y)\,dy = \int 0\, dy = C_3,$$
and the antiderivative on $(-\infty,0),$
$$\int g(y)\,dy = \int -2y^{-3}\, dy = \frac1{y^2} + C_4.$$

There is still no way to make this into a single function that is continuous at zero.
So the best we can do is to say that
$$\int\left(\frac1{\lvert y\rvert^3} - \frac1{y^3}\right)\,dy =
\begin{cases}
 C_3 & y \geq 0, \\
 \dfrac1{y^2} + C_4 & y < 0.
\end{cases}
$$